# Using package main for all files, still says undefined

Tags: go

I have 3 files currently, they all have `package main` at the top.

```
GOPATH/src/example.com/myweb/main.go
GOPATH/src/example.com/myweb/api.go
GOPATH/src/example.com/myweb/viewmodels/home.go
```

When I compile I get the error:

```
./main.go:21: undefined: Home
./main.go:39: api.Home undefined (type API has no field or method Home)
```

I am compiling using:

```
go build
```

If I do this:

```
go build main.go api.go viewmodels/home.go
```

It says no such file or directory and then a path to a file that doesnt' exist:

```
GOPATH/src/example.com/myweb/viewmodels.main.go
```

If I am using package main, should this just work with go build ?

Comment: Your source files should be under `$GOPATH/src` directory, not directly under `$GOPATH`

Comment: Unfortunately it will likely be hard to tell you exactly what the problem is without seeing your actual code.  One thing to check (after moving everything under `src` directory) is what package name you are setting in home.go.  home.go is not in main - it is in package `viewmodels`.  You would import it into `main.go` with `import myweb/viewmodels`

Comment: @sberry they are under src, i updated my question.

Comment: @sberry when  changed the package name in home.go to viewmodels, I get this error:  ```main.go:9:2: cannot find package "myweb/viewmodels" in any of:
 /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.1/libexec/src/myweb/viewmodels (from $GOROOT)
 /dev/golang/src/myweb/viewmodels (from $GOPATH)```

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice the `example.com` before.  Your import would be `import example.com/myweb/viewmodels`

Comment: And your package declaration in `home.go` would be `package viewmodels`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix two different packages in one directory. Each directory is its own package.

The go documentation (see: [golang.org/doc/code.html](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)) states the following about packages that is relevant to your situation:

> - Each package consists of one or more Go source files in a single directory.
> - The path to a package's directory determines its import path.

The solution to your problem is:

1. Use `package viewmodels` for `$GOPATH/src/example.com/myweb/viewmodels/home.go`
2. Use `package main` for `$GOPATH/src/example.com/myweb/main.go` and `$GOPATH/src/example.com/myweb/api.go`
3. Add `import "example.com/myweb/viewmodels"` to the files using the `viewmodels` package (e.g. main.go, api.go)

Your project would look something like this:

[image: Screenshot of the possible project structure with a main package and a viewmodels package in a sub-directory]